# Understanding w3c documentation on display:table-cell

Tags: html, css

I was just reading about the display property and came across the following paragraph ::

> Table Layout requires that a table-cell box must have a table-row
>   parent box.
>
> If it is misparented, like so:

```
<div style="display:block;">
  <div style="display:table-cell">...</div>
</div>
```

> It will generate wrapper boxes around itself, producing a structure
>   like:

```
block box
└anonymous table box
 └anonymous table-row-group box
  └anonymous table-row box
   └table-cell box
```

> Even if the parent is another internal table element, if it’s not the
>   correct one, wrapper boxes will be generated. For example, in the
>   following markup:

```
<div style="display:table;">
  <div style="display:table-row">
    <div style="display:table-cell">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Anonymous wrapper box generation will produce:

```
table box
└anonymous table-row-group box
 └table-row box
  └table-cell box
```

> This "fix-up" ensures that table layout has a predictable structure to
>   operate on.

This piece of information can be found **[HERE](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-display/#layout-specific-display)** .

But when I have the following code in my html doc:

```
<div style="display:block;">
  <div style="display:table-cell">...</div>
</div>
```

I never see any additional elements such as `table-row` and `display:table`, as described by the documentation.

Can somebody explain?

Comment: In CSS table the row is not required if it's the only row in the table, as I known of. The parent container should be set to `display:table` or `inline-table` in order to use all the awesome table features, such as `table-layout:fixed`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It says the boxes generated are anonymous. This means that the boxes that are generated have no associated elements, and the DOM is not modified. The boxes are there so that the table can be *rendered* correctly; this has no bearing on the DOM whatsoever.

Comment: thanks superstar ! but they should have really highlighted the word `anonymous` , Thanks though !